# How can i write code in a separate .cs file instead of along with source code

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

I am a beginner. I am trying to learn ajax tab control. I have a 3 tabs each one with a few text boxes and a submit button. The problem is when i double click on a button it takes me to source code(html) i want write code for button click even on a .cs file. How do i do that?

```
       <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1"   runat="server">
    </asp:ToolkitScriptManager>
         <b>Tabs Demonstration</b> <br /><br />
    <asp:TabContainer runat="server" ID="Tabs" Height="138px" ActiveTabIndex="0" 
        Width="402px">
        <asp:TabPanel runat="server" ID="Panel1" HeaderText="Address">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:UpdatePanel ID="updatePanel1" runat="server">
                    <ContentTemplate>
                        <table>
                            <tr><td class="style1">First Name:</td><td class="style1"><asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server" /></td></tr>
                            <tr><td>Address:</td><td><asp:TextBox ID="txtAddress" runat="server" /></td></tr>
                            <tr><td>
                                <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Submit" /></td></tr>
                        </table>
                   </ContentTemplate>
                </asp:UpdatePanel>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:TabPanel>

        <asp:TabPanel runat="server" ID="Panel3" HeaderText="Email" >
            <ContentTemplate>
                Email: <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmail" runat="server" />

            <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Button" /></ContentTemplate>
        </asp:TabPanel>

        <asp:TabPanel runat="server" ID="Panel2" HeaderText="Login Details">
            <ContentTemplate>
             <table>
           <tr> <td>User Name:</td><td><asp:TextBox ID="txtUser" runat="server" /></td></tr>
           <tr> <td>Password:</td><td><asp:TextBox ID="txtPass" runat="server" /><asp:Button ID="Button3" runat="server"
                   Text="Button" /></td></tr>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:TabPanel>

    </asp:TabContainer>


</form>
```

Comment: Are you using the asp control for the button or the html input tag ?

Comment: i am using asp control for button

Comment: I guess that you come with a `WinForms` background... Do you try to double-click the button in design view so that Visual Studio will automatically create the method to handle the event?

Comment: Well if you doubleclick the button it should create the event for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this manually to your button in `.aspx` page by adding **OnClick="Button1_Click"**:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
```

then in your code-behind `.aspx.cs` (press `F7` while in `.aspx` in Visual Studio) write:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}
```

or for `.aspx.vb`

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click Button1_Click(sender, e)

'Some other codes

End Sub
```

Now when the button is clicked, the code in `Button1_Click` gets executed.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try the following [Tip: regenerate aspx.designer.cs files when corrupted](http://www.undermyhat.org/blog/2009/07/tip-regenerate-aspx-designer-cs-files-when-corrupted/) (also used  for this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9595073/674700)).

In your case, try the following actions:

1. Locate the corrupted `aspx.designer.cs` file through the Solution Explorer
2. Delete only the `designer.cs` file from your project
3. Right-click your main `.aspx` file and select *Convert to Web Application*.

Check if the problem is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

simply create a **OnClick** event of button like this.

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
```

goto your property window (press f4), goto event and click on OnClick text box and press enter automatically your OnClick event add in you code.

Answer (score 0):

You can also bind the the click - event
i.e:

```
page_preinit(object sender,system.eventargs e)
{
   mybutton.onclikc += myhandler();
}

private void myhandler(object sender,system.eventargs e)
{
   // do code logic here :)
}
```